# Having issue while extracting version number from pom using xPath

Tags: python, java, xml, maven, xpath

I'm having issue extracting the version number from POM. Can someone help me with it ?

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <artifactId>watcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.test.file</groupId>
    <name>file-watcher</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <relativePath/>
        <version>2.6.1</version> 
    </parent>

</project>
```

**XPATH Expression:**

```
//project/version/text()
```

**Error:** This is returning no match found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath here is correct, it should return `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`
It can be simulated on XPath simulators like [this](http://xpather.com/)
[image: This is what I see there]
So it's quite clear your problem is not with the XPath expression while with what you doing with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your elements are in a default namespace. So try a namespace-agnostic XPath-1.0 expression like the following:

```
/*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='version']/text()
```

Its output is

> 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

as desired.